# Translating my blood, your blood, our blood into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

My sister and I are getting this phrase tattooed. I’d like to do it in Latin. More of an ode to our love of history and so that it’s really just for us, our secret.

I believe the translation is:
“ sanguis meus, sanguis tuus, sanguis noster”

Can this group confirm or adjust?

Thank you!

Comment: This could really be its own question, but I wonder if that could be simplified to something like _sanguis meus, tuus, noster_.

Comment: No answer after ten days... The translation you provide is formally correct, but it doesn’t sound good Latin, and I don‘t know exactly why... I would express the same concept by complete different proposals that wouldn’t qualify as _translations_ of the title sentence. I suppose most experts here have the same doubts.